# Error with sub query using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server, subquery, variable-assignment, multiple-tables, row-number

Good day,

In a WHILE statement I am running, one of the variable assignments I'm attempting is to use a sub query in conjunction with row_number() to pull out each specific ID from a column and sum a monetary value from another table, per each ID. I am working in MS SQL 2008.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SET @value =(SELECT PaymentAmount FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C.CategoryID ASC) AS RowNum,
   SUM(O.PaymentAmount)
   FROM Orders O
   INNER JOIN OrderDetails OD ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
   INNER JOIN Products_Joined PJ ON OD.ProductCode = PJ.ProductCode
   INNER JOIN Categories_Products_Link CPL ON PJ.ProductID = CPL.ProductID
   INNER JOIN Categories C ON CPL.CategoryID = C.CategoryID
   GROUP BY C.CategoryID
) AS Num
WHERE RowNum = @counter)
```

The error I'm running into is in regards to no column was specified for column 2 of 'Num'.
Thoughts? Ideas? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Provide an alias; `SUM(O.PaymentAmount) As TotalAmount`

Comment: `PaymentAmount` is not found inside the subquery.

Comment: Select the alias; `(SELECT TotalAmount FROM `